# 日本語に違和感: トップページの質問一覧の下にある「もっと見ますか?...」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

> もっと見ますか?質問の完全なリストまたは人気の高いタグを参照してください。未回答の質問への回答にご協力ください。

- 「完全なリスト」に違和感
- 「もっと見ますか?」という応答形式の書き方はあまり日本語のサイトでは見ない印象があります
- 「ご協力ください」はユーザーが回答を投稿する気がないことを前提にしているような感じがする

英語版

> Looking for more? Browse the complete list of questions, or popular tags. Help us answer unanswered questions.

Comment: 確かに「もっと見ますか？」には少し違和感を感じるかもしれませんね。英語版の"Looking for more?"は自然な感じがしますが、日本語だと不自然に感じる理由はやはり文化的なものでしょうか。ここは意訳をして「もっと見るには」とか「さらに表示するには」という言葉も使えるかもしれませんね。

Comment: 「質問の完全なリスト」は「全ての質問」が良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

> 質問をもっと見るには、全ての質問のリストか人気タグ一覧をご覧ください。未解決の質問では回答を募集中です。

Comment: +1とても解りやすいと思います。